# remove header part from some .phtml pages

Tags: layout, xml, header

visit these links : http://4.videomergerapp.com/

we removed the complete header part [except logo ] in the following page :

http://4.videomergerapp.com/marketplace/

I want to hide complete header part from some other pages also.

what code we need to add to done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work for you

```
<marketplace_index_index>
    <reference name="header">
        <remove name="top.search"/>
    </reference>

 </marketplace_index_index>
```

and cart remove from css

```
 .div_link-cart {
  display:none !important
}
```

Comment: i did it, but its removing logo also, what we need to do to keep only logo

Comment: you want to remove search?

Comment: yes, i wnat to keep only logo....

Comment: remove  top link also? and cart?

Comment: want to remove everything except logo.....

Comment: updated the answer check it

Comment: only cart button removed, top search and top links are still there.....

Comment: .header_search { display:none !important;} use css..

Comment: you are suggesting better to use internal css, instead of xml files ?

Comment: You don't want permanent remove the thing so it quick  solution.