# remove social networking icons from some pages

Tags: layout, extensions, xml

visit this link : http://4.videomergerapp.com/marketplace/

we are using an extension to display social networking links on right side of the page.

on right side, you can see "social networking links" : fb, google + ...etc.

I want to remove those links from some .phtml pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with css

```
.social-icons {
      display:none !important; // this will work for you..
    }
```

Comment: but i want to hide on only particlar pages, if i use this code, it will hide from all pages....

Comment: no use in that page mean  add on those page only. add css inside the phtml file

Comment: okay,i have to use internal css, thanks , it worked.... please check this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89683/remove-header-part-from-some-phtml-pages